# Stack overflow push rejected with no reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to push to heroku and it get's to the `verifying deploy...` step but then rejects the push for no reason:

```
remote: =====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
remote: =====> Detected Framework: Ruby
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.1.2
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.7.12
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
remote: Verifying deploy..................................................
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to <APP_NAME_OMITTED>.
remote:
 ! [remote rejected] test_botched_deploy -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/APP-NAME-OMITTED.git'
```

I'm not sure what to google for this. Is there a way to enable a verbose mode for heroku deploys?

Comment: `git push heroku master -v` will make it more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that everything works locally before you push, a good place to start is to make sure you have pushed a current version of your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock.`